# Start a second function, after the first one has been completed.

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have a problem with jQuery & AJAXs.

I have 2 functions, doing some AJAXs - Stuff:

## 1:

```
getSelectedRoom($chosenRoom)
```

and

## 2:

```
getDeviceTable("all", "div#DeviceTables",0,1,1,0,1,$chosenRoom)
```

The first Function creates a div and inserts an image. Now, when this is done, I need the height of that div with the image inside. Therefore I need the second function to wait, until the first function is done with everything.

I thought the following code would solve my problem, but the second function starts sometimes, bevor the div is ready and gets a height of 0px.

```
$.when( 
    // Wohnungsgrundriss anzeigen
    getSelectedRoom($chosenRoom) 

).done(
    // Device Tablle mit allen verfügbaren Geräten füllen.
    getDeviceTable("all", "div#DeviceTables",0,1,1,0,1,$chosenRoom)

);
```

Is there a way to ensure, that function 1 has been completed, before function 2 starts?

Here is also the code of those functions:

```js
function getSelectedRoom($chosenRoom){
// Ausgewählten Raum mit platzierten Geräten anzeigen
 // Raumgrundriss laden
 $.post("getSelectedRoom.php", {chosenRoom : $chosenRoom},
  function($echoData){
   $("div#SelectedRoom").html($echoData);
   $(".droppable").droppable({
    // Nur Objekte die komplett drin sind werden akzeptiert.
    tolerance: "fit",

    // Funktionsaufruf wenn ein Gerät in das Bild gedropt wird.
    drop: function( event, ui ){
     var $parent = ui.draggable;
     var $draggedElement = $(ui.draggable);
     var $dropZone = $(this);

     // Berechnen der Position relativ zum Zimmergrundriss (als absolute Werte in Px)
     var $leftOffset = $parent.offset().left - $dropZone.offset().left;
     var $topOffset = $dropZone.offset().top - $parent.offset().top;

     // Umrechnen der absoluten Werte zu prozentualen Werten, abhängig vom Zimmergrundriss (Zimmergrundriss = 1000%)
      // Grundrissgröße bestimmen
      var $groundplotWidth = $("div#SelectedRoom").width();
      var $groundplotHeight = $("div#SelectedRoom").height();

      // Umrechnung in %
      $leftOffset = Math.round($leftOffset * ( 1000 / $groundplotWidth ));
      $topOffset = Math.round($topOffset * ( 1000 / $groundplotHeight ));

     //Speichern der Position in der MySQL Tabelle
     $.post("insertDevice.php", {chosenRoom : $chosenRoom, ID : $(ui.draggable).attr('id') , X : $leftOffset, Y : $topOffset},
      function($echoData){
       // Platzhalter für eventuelle Bestätigung nach dem erfolgreichen speichern...
       console.log($echoData);
      });

     // Debugging:
     console.log(".....................");
     console.log(".Einfügen............");
     console.log("chosenRoom: " + $chosenRoom);
     console.log("ID: " + $(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
     console.log("X: " + $leftOffset);
     console.log("Y: " + $topOffset);
     console.log(".....................");

    },
    // Funktionsaufruf wenn ein Gerät aus dem Bild gedropt (war zuvor im Bild) wird.
    out: function( event, ui ){
     $.post("delDevice.php", {chosenRoom : $chosenRoom, ID : $(ui.draggable).attr('id')}, 
      function($echoData){
       // Platzhalter für eventuelle Bestätigung nach dem erfolgreichen löschen...

       // Debugging:
       console.log(".....................");
       console.log(".Entfernen...........");
       console.log("chosenRoom: " + $chosenRoom);
       console.log("ID: " + $(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
       console.log(".....................");
       console.log($echoData);

      });
    }
   });
  });
}

function getDeviceTable($tbl, $target, $splt_id, $splt_zustand, $splt_name, $splt_bedienel, $noText, $chosenRoom){
 if ( $tbl == "all" ) {        // Abfrage für alle Tabellen

  $text =   '<p>Wählen Sie eine Tabelle um die darin enthaltenen Geräte zu bearbeiten.</p>';
  $print =  '<p id="tblCON"></p>' + 
     '<p id="tblFUN"></p>' + 
     '<p id="tblSEN"></p>';
  
  if($noText != 1){   
   $print = $text + $print;
  };

  $($target).html($print);

  // Beide AJAX Calls werden lsogeschickt. then() wird ausgeführt, wenn beide Callbacks durchgeführt wurden.
  $.when(
   getDeviceTable("CONNECTION", "p#tblCON", $splt_id, $splt_zustand, $splt_name, $splt_bedienel, $noText, $chosenRoom),
   getDeviceTable("FUNK", "p#tblFUN", $splt_id, $splt_zustand, $splt_name, $splt_bedienel, $noText, $chosenRoom)
  ).done( positionDevices($chosenRoom) );

  if($noText  != 1){
   getDeviceTable("SENSOR", "p#tblSEN", $splt_id, $splt_zustand, $splt_name, $splt_bedienel); 
  }
  
 } else {           // Abfrage für einzelne Tabelle
  $.post("getDeviceTable.php", {tbl : $tbl, splt_id : $splt_id, splt_zustand : $splt_zustand, splt_name : $splt_name, splt_bedienel : $splt_bedienel, noText : $noText,
  }, function($echoData){
   // Ausgabe der Tabelle im Targetbereich
   if($noText != 1){ 
    if ($tbl == "CONNECTION") {
     $echoData = '<h3>Digitale Ein- & Ausgänge</h3>' + $echoData;
    } else if ($tbl == "FUNK") {
     $echoData = '<h3>Funkschalter & -Steckdosen</h3>' + $echoData;
    } else if ($tbl == "SENSOR") {
     $echoData = '<h3>Temperatursensoren</h3>' + $echoData;
    } else {
     alert("Die Tabelle \"" + $tbl + "\" ist der Funktion getDeviceTable() nicht bekannt!");
    }
   }
   
   if($noText == 1){
   // Ausgabe als aufgeklappte Tabellen
    $($target).html('').append($echoData).fadeOut(0).fadeIn(500);
   // Drag & Drop in der Zimmerverwaltung:
    $(".draggable").draggable({ 
     cancel: false,
     revert: function(event, ui) {
      // jQuery 1.x Version:
      // $(this).data("draggable")
      // jQuery 2.x Version:
      // $(this).data("ui-draggable")
      $(this).data("ui-draggable").originalPosition = {
          top : 0,
          left : 0
      };
      // return boolean
      return !event;
      // Kurzform für: return event !== false ? false : true;
     }
    });
    $(".draggable").css('position','relative');

   }else{
    // Standardausgabe der Tabellen mit Fade Effekt und eingeklappten Tabellen
    $($target).html('').append($echoData).fadeOut(0).ready(hide_all_tr('#'+$tbl,0)).fadeIn(500);
   }
  });
 }
}

function positionDevices($chosenRoom){
// Wenn die Tabellen geladen sind, sollen alle Geräte im Raum an die entsprechende Position geschoben werden.
 // Feststellen welche Geräte im Raum sind!
 $.post("getSelRoomDevices.php", {chosenRoom : $chosenRoom},
  function($echoData){

  // Alle Geräte in $echoData in Position bringen!
   // Debugging
   console.log(".....................");
   console.log(".Laden...............");
   console.log("chosenRoom: " + $chosenRoom);
   console.log($echoData);

   // Tabelle versteckt ausgeben
   $("#hiddenTable").hide().html($echoData);

   // Wie viele Geräte sind in der Tabelle?
   var $anzDevice = $("div#hiddenTable table > tbody > tr").length;

   //Zeile für Zeile auswerten
   for($zeile = 1; $zeile <= $anzDevice; $zeile++){
    // ID & Position auslesen
    $ID = $("div#hiddenTable table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + $zeile + ") > td:nth-child(1)").html();
    $X  = $("div#hiddenTable table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + $zeile + ") > td:nth-child(2)").html();
    $Y  = $("div#hiddenTable table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + $zeile + ") > td:nth-child(3)").html();

    // Debugging
    console.log("ID: " + $ID);
    console.log("X: " + $X);
    console.log("Y: " + $Y);
    console.log("Moved Button ID: button#" + $ID);

    // Grundrissgröße bestimmen
    var $groundplotWidth = $("div#SelectedRoom").width();
    var $groundplotHeight = $("div#SelectedRoom").height();
    $groundplotHeight = $groundplotHeight * (-1);

    // Debugging
    console.log("Grundrissbreite: " + $groundplotWidth + "px");
    console.log("Grundrisshöhe: " + $groundplotHeight + "px");

    // Berechnen der Position in px vom Bildrand
    var $posInsidePicX = ($groundplotWidth / 1000) * $X;
    var $posInsidePicY = ($groundplotHeight / 1000) * $Y * (-1);

    // Debugging
    console.log("Position X des Gerätes im Bild: " + $posInsidePicX + "px");
    console.log("Position Y des Gerätes im Bild: " + $posInsidePicY + "px");

    // Berechnen des Offset des Grundrissbildes:
    var $offsetOfPicX = $("div#SelectedRoom").offset().left;
    var $offsetOfPicY = $("div#SelectedRoom").offset().top;
    $offsetOfPicY = $offsetOfPicY * (-1);

    // Debugging
    console.log("Offset X des Bildes: " + $offsetOfPicX + "px");
    console.log("Offset Y des Bildes: " + $offsetOfPicY + "px");

    // Position im Bild auf Offset des Bildes drauf rechnen um absolute Position zu erhalten
    var $absX = $posInsidePicX + $offsetOfPicX;
    var $absY = $posInsidePicY + $offsetOfPicY;
    $absY = $absY * (-1);

    // Debugging
    console.log("Absolute Position X: " + $absX + "px");
    console.log("Absolute Position Y: " + $absY + "px");

    // Positionieren des Device in die Absolute Position
    $("button#" + $ID).offset({top: $absY, left: $absX});

    // Debugging
    console.log(".....................");
   }

   // Debugging
   console.log("Anzahl enthaltener Geräte: " + $anzDevice);
   console.log(".....................");
  });
}
```

Comment: `$.when()` accepts one type of argument only, a promise.   It has no magic powers to know when a function is done.  It just calls its done callback when the promise or promises you pass it are all resolved.  As such you can't just pass `$.when()` a plain old function that returns nothing and expect it to do anything useful.

Comment: Ok. But what should be returned to $.when() to make it work?

Comment: @jfriend00, the code clearly needs fixing but "$.when() accepts one type of argument only, a promise" is totally incorrect. `$.when(value)` (a promise resolved with the specified value) is a very commonly used jQuery expression. Also `$q.when(value)` in angular.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - OK, fine you can pass a value to `$.when()`.  It wouldn't do the OP any good though for their problem and they're passing it `undefined`.  I will clean up the answer.

Comment: @jfriend00, agreed, $.when(value)` won't help the OP, at least not this time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your code:

First, as I explained in the comments `$.when()` has no magic powers and it can only do its job of notifying you when an async operation is done if you pass it one or more promises.  You're passing it the return result from `getSelectedRoom()` which is `undefined` so `$.when()` isn't being passed a promise and thus is just calling it's `.done()` handler immediately.  And, once you're returning a promise from `getSelectedRoom()`, you don't need to use `$.when()` at all because you just have a single promise which you can just use `.then()` on directly.  `$.when()` is only useful for notifying of async completion when you have more than one promise and you want to know when they are all done.

This issue be fixed quite easily by just changing this:

```
function getSelectedRoom($chosenRoom){
// Ausgewählten Raum mit platzierten Geräten anzeigen
    // Raumgrundriss laden
    $.post("getSelectedRoom.php", {chosenRoom : $chosenRoom},
    ....
}
```

to this:

```
function getSelectedRoom($chosenRoom){
// Ausgewählten Raum mit platzierten Geräten anzeigen
    // Raumgrundriss laden
    return $.post("getSelectedRoom.php", {chosenRoom : $chosenRoom},
    ....
}
```

Now, you're returning the jQuery ajax promise from `$.post()` from `getSelectedRoom()`, so it's now possible to do this:

```
getSelectedRoom(...).then(function() {
    getDeviceTable("all", "div#DeviceTables",0,1,1,0,1,$chosenRoom);

});
```

Second, if you're trying to measure the size of some HTML that you just inserted, that may or may not work because the browser may or may not have done a layout/repaint yet (whether the repaint has happened will depend upon some implementation details of the promise library).  You can guarantee that a repaint has happened by doing this:

```
getSelectedRoom(...).then(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        getDeviceTable("all", "div#DeviceTables",0,1,1,0,1,$chosenRoom);
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very very much! Your explanation and examples were extremely helpful!